# Solution for a 35 monitor user case

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga

I have a question about a multi-monitor solution for a school. They have some statistics that they would like to be displayed over no less than 35 monitors. Does anybody know of such hardware? 
The only thing I can think of is a VGA multiplier(not splitter), but all ports have to work simultaneously.

I am having trouble finding such a device. Any feedback is appreciated.

To be fare I think I need an active splitter.

Comment: Each monitor should display the same?

Comment: Yes. I found a 32-port splitter but not a 64-port one. I can just buy 2 32-port ones and clone the output from the PC.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 35 times the same

There is no such solution.
Also, even if you would use DVI instead of VGA cables you can at most get to about 10 meters without using repeaters.
Solutions like this are usualy done by hooking up a small form factor pc or embedded device to each screen and stream the data over the network using software like [xibo](http://xibo.org.uk/)

Comment: Not a solution for them. They specifically said that they do not want a one PC/one monitor solution. The whole system is for one room. Therefore less than 10m of cable.

Comment: well if you can find a splitter and the cable lengths are ok http://www.cablek.com/technical-reference/vga-cable-length-vs-resolution